# Sparx EA Reporting - Understanding Loops

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to create a Sparx Enterprise Architect Report and need some assistance in understanding the Reporting Sections and how loops are processed.  My intention is to get as simple report of a process diagram, and then show all linked requirements.. the structure would be as follows:

- Package
- List of Elements in Package (as a table)
- Then for each Element
- List of Linked Requirements (as a table)

This is how I have setup the configuration: [image]

The template fragment is simply a query that returns all requirements which are linked to elements within the current package.

There must be an easier way to simply list specific elements in a package. then re-iterate the same list of elements to process their connections?

Thanks!

Comment: if I understand, you want to show every requirement of each element, recursively, in a package?

Comment: yes. that is correct. however. I wanted to summarize all elements (element + Notes) in a table first... THEN ... show requirements for each element... Its slightly different to just recursively scanning...